# How to run multiple exe programs at the same time using python?

Tags: python

I want to run multiple exe programs at the same time using python. 
Can you help me?

```
import os
    os.system( '"C:\\Users\\FOLDER\\MLTPad1.exe"' )
    os.system('"C:\\Users\\FOLDER2\\MLTPad2.exe"')
```

Comment: Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system()`. It gives you more options to handles processes.

Comment: You have to use threading, Check threading module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import threading 

def exe1(): 

    os.system( '"C:\\Users\\FOLDER\\MLTPad1.exe"' )

def exe2(): 
    os.system('"C:\\Users\\FOLDER2\\MLTPad2.exe"')

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # creating thread 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=exe1, args=()) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=exe2, args=()) 

    # starting thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # starting thread 2 
    t2.start() 

    # wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
    t1.join() 
    # wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
    t2.join() 

    # both threads completely executed 
    print("Done!")
```

What happens here is that both your exes are put into separate functions, which then are run parallely using the concept of multithreading implemented via threading class of Python.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

However, I got the following error. Can you help me?

Error occurs as below


  File "C:\Users\khc41\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/khc41/OneDrive/Desktop/MultiThreading/MultiThreading.py", line 12
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=exe1, args=())
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: You need to indent the code after `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: @DanielKim I am glad i could help. If the answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @Gobind Deep Singh Thank you for your help!! It works. Can you help me with one more thing? If I use this code, the output files are created at the same folder that the python file is located, then the output files of the same file name are overlapped so that error occurs. How can I make output files created in each folder, Folder and Folder2.

Comment: @DanielKim Can you update your question with your latest code

Comment: @Gobind Deep Singh In this case, the output files obtained from two executions are generated in the same folder that includes the python file. Thus, the output files are overlapped, and errors occur. I want the output files obtained from execution in separate folders, case1 and case2, to be generated in each folder "case1" and "case2" separately. Can you help me? My code is as below

Comment: import threading 
import os

def exe1():
os.system(r"C:\Users\khc41\OneDrive\Desktop\MultiThreading\Case1\B000_mltsim.exe")

def exe2():
os.system(r"C:\Users\khc41\OneDrive\Desktop\MultiThreading\Case2\B000_mltsim.exe")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # creating thread 
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=exe1, args=()) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=exe2, args=()) 
    # starting thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # starting thread 2 
    t2.start()     
    t1.join() 
    t2.join()

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to spawn separate processes, then you can use something like

```
from subprocess import Popen
print(Popen(['notepad.exe']).pid)
print(Popen(['calc.exe']).pid)
```